# Show that the three sets $A\setminus B$, $A\cap B$, and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint and that their union is $A\cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

To prove they are disjoint, suppose for the sake of contradiction that they aren't i.e., $\exists x: x\in (A\setminus B) \cap (A\cap B) \cap (B\setminus A) \iff x \in A\setminus B$ and $x\in A\cap B$ and $x\in B\setminus A \iff (x\in A \land x \notin B) \text{ and } (x\in A \land x\in B)\text{ and }(x \in B \land x\notin A)$ so $x\in A$ and $x \notin A$ and $x \in B$ and $x \notin B$ which is a contradiction. Thus by the definition of the empty set, $(A\setminus B) \cap (A\cap B) \cap (B\setminus A)=\emptyset$.

---

For the second one let $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A) \iff x\in A\setminus B$ or $x \in A\cap B$ or $x \in B\setminus A \iff (x\in A \text{ and } x\notin B)$ or $(x\in A \text{ and } x\in B)$ or $(x \in B \text{ and } x\notin A)$.

If $x\notin A$ then $x\notin B$ or $x \in B$ or $x \in A \implies x\in A$ or $x\in B \implies x\in A\cup B$.

If $x\in A$ then $(x\in A \text{ and } x\notin B)$ or $(x\in A \text{ and } x\in B)$ or $x\in B \implies x\in A$ or $x\in B\implies x\in A\cup B$.

In both cases $x\in A\cup B$ thus $ (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A) \subseteq A\cup B$.

Now  suppose $x \in A\cup B$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ and I'm not sure how to continue here.

My questions are: is my first proof correct? Is the second proof up to that point correct? If so, how could I continue in order to show $ A\cup B \subseteq (A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B) \cup (B\setminus A)$?

**Edit:** The first proof should be proving the sets are pairwise disjoint. Here is a post where this gets answered for one of these cases and the rest are similar. [Proof that $A \cap B$ and $A \setminus B$ are disjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833667/proof-that-a-cap-b-and-a-setminus-b-are-disjoint)

Comment: I wonder for the first part if you should actually show that they are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: For the second part treat the cases 1) $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, 2) $x \not\in A$ and $x \in B$ and 3) $x \in A$ and $x \not\in B$

Comment: This is from Tao's Analysis I and the only mention of the word "disjoint" up to that point is that "Two sets $A$,$B$ are said to be "disjoint" if $A\cap B=\emptyset$"

Comment: In that case, you should prove that the three sets are disjoint using two sets at a time, as the definition only applies to two sets

Comment: Ok then, should I also do that for union? Because it isn't very clear but I tend to agree with you because these proofs look rather ugly.

Comment: To prove that the union equals $A \cup B$, you should use all three sets.

Comment: How did you make that distinction? Is it since the definition of disjointness only mentions a realtion between two sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the properties involved, one has that:
\begin{align*}
(A\backslash B)\cap(A\cap B) & = (A\cap B^{c})\cap(A\cap B)\\\\
& = A\cap(B^{c}\cap(A\cap B))\\\\
& = A\cap(B^{c}\cap(B\cap A))\\\\
& = A\cap ((B^{c}\cap B)\cap A)\\\\
& = A\cap (\varnothing\cap A)\\\\
& = A\cap\varnothing = \varnothing
\end{align*}

Similarly, we prove that $A\cap B$ and $B\backslash A$ are disjoint. As to the third case, we may proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
(A\backslash B)\cap(B\backslash A) & = (A\cap B^{c})\cap(B\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap(B^{c}\cap(B\cap A^{c}))\\\\
& = A\cap((B^{c}\cap B)\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap(\varnothing\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = A\cap\varnothing = \varnothing 
\end{align*}

As to the union, let us do it in two steps. First, it results that
\begin{align*}
(A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap B) & = (A\cap B^{c})\cup(A\cap B)\\\\
& = A\cap(B^{c}\cup B) = A
\end{align*}

And finally we obtain the desired claim:
\begin{align*}
(A\backslash B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup(B\backslash A) & = A\cup(B\backslash A)\\\\
& = A\cup(B\cap A^{c})\\\\
& = (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup A^{c})\\\\
& = A\cup B
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I did prove them in the end but these are very nice and clear proofs. I especially appreciate the union proof since it is much more clear than my way and thus gives more insight. When I started proving these, I also tried not picking an element $x$ and doing the proofs like that but I was worried if the sets were empty or not. Is this a valid concern? Should I mention something about that in this type of proof?

Comment: @Eric You can split it into cases if you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to prove that the three sets are pairwise disjoint. You can obviously have $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$ without any two being disjoint.
2. You make unnecessarily heavy work of the first direction. Delete “let”. Then just note that what is on the right after the second biconditional is trivially the inclusive disjunction of $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.
3. And you need to do no more work for the other direction, because note you have proved biconditionals. So you can equally go in the opposite direction from the last to the first and you are done!

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant for 3? Is it that what I did to prove the direction $(\implies)$ can all work in reverse? I thought I lost the equivalence when I started considering cases.

Comment: You didn’t need to consider cases. It is trivial logic that  ((p and not-q) or (p and q) or (not-p and q)) is equivalent to the inclusive disjunction (p or q).